# How to copy text string from nfc tag

Tags: nfc

I'm trying to copy a string of text from a nfc tag, but the only option I've been able to find is displaying the text with no ability to copy it (its a complex string with letters and numbers). Best case scenario would be to insert the string where the cursor is at the moment the tag is pressed, but I'm okay with somehow getting the string to the clipboard to paste.
If this isn't the right place to ask this question, if you could tell me where I could find the answer, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Are you trying to develop an app that does this? If that's the case, you would probably have better luck on our sister site, http://stackoverflow.com. Questions about development are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NXP's [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite) app can copy the text from a text record on a scanned NFC tag to the clipboard. There are other apps with similar functionality. Copying text from text records on NFC tags is not something that's built into Android without installing and running an app.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it out and I can in fact copy it to the clipboard. This is a step in the right direction! Is there any way for a phone that does not have this app installed to copy the string to its clipboard / paste to the location of the cursor? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @Kevin Only by installing another app that does that.